# How to pull a variable from a method to the main method?

Tags: c#, methods

I'm trying to just pull the return variable out of a few methods that are set up exactly like this into another method. I want to do it in a way that is efficient to the computer as I am writing a console application as this is the main thing that I know how to use at the moment. The reason for this is to use SQL to connect to a database but my connection is going to be inside a connection test which then will hold the connection within the main method so I need help with passing the variables. Here is the relevant code.

```
 //Create a method to get database name
public static string databname()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the database name.\n");
    string dbasename = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return dbasename;
}

//Create a method to get database password
public static string databpass()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter database password.\n");
    string dbasepass = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return dbasepass;
}

//Create a method to get username
public static string usernames()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter access username.\n");
    string username = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return username;
}

//Create a method to get user's password
public static string pass()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter access password.\n");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine();
    return password;
}
```

I would like to try and pass the variables in the above methods to the below places as I don't know how to in C#. I've tried and looked up tutorials and code snippets and none have worked for me so far.

```
//Try to run program
try
{
    //Create display for user to enter info through the methods
    string databaseName = databname();
    string databasePass = databpass();
    string username = usernames();
    string password = pass();
```

Comment: You're already reading the return value of `pass()` into the main program?  What else would you like to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do? pass the variables `databaseName`, `databasePass`, etc to another method or class? For me hard to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Sorry, don't really understand what blocked you, you already get what you need from console input, would you like to create a connection string basing on what you get?

Comment: The way I have it, it's reading the method and then rereading where it is stated at the try and I want to stop the double reading and just pass the variables into the main so that I have the declared for me to be able to use them without declaring them at creation. I don't know why it's reading the methods before it is called.

Comment: Are you just trying to screw with us dude?

Comment: No. I'm not. I'm being serious. I'll provide a screenshot if possible on here. I tried pasting a screenshot. I can mail it to people if need be. Just shoot me your email as I have a picture printscreened.

Comment: One of the hallmarks of professional programming is consistent naming conventions.

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know how to pass back a local variable  inside a method back to the caller in addition to the return value? Example: say `sampleVar` is declared in `pass()` - you want to return `password` and `sampleVar` back to the `main` method when you invoke `pass()`?

Comment: @ChaosPandion I know but I'm just trying to get the functionality right. Before the try section, it is reading all the methods up top so when it does hit the try, it's redoing the process over again. I just want to grab the return value only. Not the first one that reads the input.

Comment: use out parameter to return multiple variable out of your method

Comment: I know how to do that in Java but it seems more tricky in C# as I've tried the exact same way but it didn't work. @IgorLozovsky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is sample code of how to use `out` parameters

in your **Main()**

```
{
...
string name,pass;
GetInputData(out name, out pass);
...

}
```

Get all in one method:

```
public static void GetInputData(out string pass, out string name)
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter name:");
name = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("Enter pass:");
pass = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is so different from Java.

Comment: It says I have to have a return in my method and when I do, I try return like this:

 return name, pass;

It says that it expects a ;
I tried it like this:

   return name;
   return pass;

It says unreachable code on the last return

Comment: Did you read any books about C#? I suggest you to read, you don't know syntax basics. Of course you cannot do like you showed in your comment. Edit your question with problematic part of code.

Comment: I found out how to do it. :) OP decided to work correctly this time. @Igor Lozovsky

Comment: Great! But I still suggest you to read any C# book, e.g. - Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform, Fifth Edition

Comment: I've read a C# book already before I did this called C# in Depth by Jon Skeet. I was just over thinking how to write code like I normally do. :) @Igor Lozovsky

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of options for returning back multiple pieces of data from a method, and this is my ordering of options that I think you should consider.

**Make a Complex Return Type**

You can make a complex type that represents the data that you want and then return an instance of that type. This is typically the pattern you should shoot for in my opinion. For example:

```
public class SomeType
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }
}
```

And your method like so:

```
public SomeType pass()
{
    SomeType instance = new SomeType();
    instance.Password = // get your password
    instance.SomeOtherValue = // get another value

    return instance;
}
```

**Set Global / Instance Variables**

Internal to your object, you can set shared variables in your code that can be read as long as you are in the same scope level. For example:

```
public class Sample
{
    public static string _sharedVariable = string.Empty;

    public static void DoSomething()
    {
        string result = DoSomethingElse();
        // Can access _sharedVariable here
    }

    protected static string DoSomething()
    {
        _sharedVariable = "hello world";
        return "sup";
    }
}
```

**Make Ref / Out Parameters**

You can return a single data type, and specify parameters to be `out` parameters which are parameters specified to be returned / changed by the method. This method should really only be used in specific instances, when the return type of a method needs to be a specific type or you are trying to enforce some kind of API restraint. For example:

```
int outputGuy = 0;

string password = pass(out outputGuy);
```

And your method would look like so:

```
public string pass(out string outputGuy)
{
     outputGuy = "some string"; // compiler error if you dont set this guy!
     return // some password
}
```

Comment: I want something a little easier as my job is to pull out records from a database table which I'll be working on if I can get my method to work. I like the last example because it makes it easier.